# Getting first principal component and reduction in variance with PCA using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pca

I am following this example here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-principal-component-analysis-scratch-python/

```
A = array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
print(A)
# calculate the mean of each column
M = mean(A.T, axis=1)
print(M)
# center columns by subtracting column means
C = A - M
print(C)
# calculate covariance matrix of centered matrix
V = cov(C.T)
print(V)
# eigendecomposition of covariance matrix
values, vectors = eig(V)
print(vectors)
print(values)
# project data
P = vectors.T.dot(C.T)
print(P.T)
```

which gives:

```
original data
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
column mean
[ 3.  4.]
centered matrix
[[-2. -2.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 2.  2.]]
covariance matrix
[[ 4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.]]
vectors
[[ 0.70710678 -0.70710678]
 [ 0.70710678  0.70710678]]
values
[ 8.  0.]
projected data
[[-2.82842712  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 2.82842712  0.        ]]
```

If I want to find the first principal direction, do I simply take the eigenvalue that corresponds to the largest eigenvector? Therefore:`[0.70710678, 0.70710678]` ?

Building upon this, is the first principal component the highest eigenvector projected onto the data? Something like:

```
vectors[:,:1].T.dot(C.T)
```

which gives:

```
array([[-2.82842712,  0.        ,  2.82842712]])
```

I just fear I have the terminology confused, or I'm oversimplifying things. Thanks in advance!

Comment: eigenvalue is an indicator on how much information you have on the corresponding eigenvector. Here you one eigenvalue = 0 it means that all the information remain on the first eigen vector = 8. It also means that your original matrix was rank 1 in other word column were correlated.
The first principal direction represent the one with most information where eigen value is max.

Comment: as @Katsu explained you don't have actually "largest eigenvector" you have largest eigenvalue. the eigenvalue corresponds to the variances of the data and the eigenvectors corespond to their direction. So you chose the right vector as the first PC. The first PC is always the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: @hamid.khb to build on this, there would be no need to calculate the variance of the 1D data after doing the dot product with the eigenvector? the eigenvalue would explain the remaining variance in the data after dimensionality reduction?

Comment: I haven't test it myself but theoreticaly yes. you can test it to be sure.

Comment: this [link](https://jdstorey.org/fas/eda_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-88-1.png) is a good visualization of what happens when you project the data on one of the PC's.